# C# Monotouch/Xamarin - iOS Bluetooth connection to multiple phones?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, bluetooth, xamarin

Does anyone know if it's possible to use Bluetooth to connect to multiple phones using C# Monotouch/Xamarin iOS?

**Update**

- I'd preferably like to connect multiple phones to one main phone
  host, all via Bluetooth (1 host and 3 or 4 clients).
- I don't know a
  great deal about bluetooth and the various profiles, so I'd be
  looking for guidance on this aspect also.

Comment: Do you want to connect one phone to multiple other phones at the same time?  What are you trying to do?  Which BT profile do you want to use?

Comment: Ultimately I'd like to be able to connect around 5 phones using Bluetooth. Is that actually possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can.

iOS 7.0 introduced the [Multipeer Connectivity](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MultipeerConnectivity/Reference/MultipeerConnectivityFramework/Introduction/Introduction.html) framework. It can work with both bluetooth and/or wifi (and can even bridge between them, pretty neat).

You can find sample code (e.g. [chat](http://www.knowing.net/index.php/2013/09/28/my-favorite-ios-7-apis-multipeer-connectivity/), [mixed with iBeacons](https://github.com/mikebluestein/FindTheMonkey)) by googling around for **Multipeer Connectivity**, **iOS** and **monotouch**.